# .net core 6 (Web API). Shared localization doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, localization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to use a shared localization with two resource files.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YjCE.png)

My `SharedResources.cs`:

```
namespace Web.Facade
{
    public class SharedResources
    {
    }
}
```

My `Startup.cs`:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           ...
           services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
           ...

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           ...
           var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "ru-RU" };
           var localizationOptions =
               new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
               .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
               .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

           app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
           ...
        }
```

I'm using localization inside my controllers and middleware.

For example, my `AuthController.cs`:

```
    [Route("api/v1/auth")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthService authService;
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer;

        private readonly ILogger<AuthController> logger;

        public AuthController(
            IAuthService authService,
            IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer,
            ILogger<AuthController> logger)
        {
            this.authService = authService;
            this.localizer = localizer;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
        public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken([FromBody] RefreshTokenDTO refreshTokenDto)
        {
            if (!RefreshTokenDTO.IsValidModel(refreshTokenDto, out var errorMessage))
            {
                return this.BadRequest(new ErrorResponse(this.localizer[errorMessage].Value));
            }
```

I called my Web API method with `Accept-Language: ru-RU` header, but received the default string `"Invalid access or refresh tokens"` instead of the expected `"Некорректный access или refresh токен"` from `SharedResources.ru-RU.resx`

I am already trying to:

1. Move `SharedResources.cs` to another folder and to project root
2. Change `SharedResources.cs` namespace
3. Change default culture

Only one thing worked for me: leave one resource file with ru-RU culture and rename it to `SharedResources.resx`. But in this case I always get localized data regardless of the `Accept-Language` header.

So, I want to use shared resources and manage culture by header. Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. My problem was the order of summoning the `middlewares`.

**Solution**: I just moved `app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions)` to the beginning of the `Configure` method and it worked!

**Explanation**:
This is due to the fact that my middleware `ExceptionMiddleware` in which the localizer is used was called earlier than the middleware `UseRequestLocalization` defining the culture passed in the header, so the default value of the strings in English was used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. One file needs modifying.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("ru-RU")
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

var localizeOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizeOptions.Value);

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried to do the same as you, except using app.Services property (because it doesn't exist). Instead I used app.ApplicationServices property. But all these changes did not help me :( 
Anyway thanks for the help!